# Moving one tick mark on y-axis to the right of the y-axis while keeping others to the left of y-axis

Tags: pgfplots

I have a plot for the function y = 15x - (1/4)x^{3}. I am labeling the local maximum value of the function with `20\sqrt{5}` on the y-axis.  I also have other tick marks on the y-axis.  I want the default tick marks to be kept on the left side of the y-axis, and I want to move only the extra tick mark to the right side of the y-axis.  Why is the command `extra y tick style={y tick label style={right, xshift=0.25em}},` moving all the tick marks to the right side of the y-axis?  What code will give me what I want with respect to the tick marks?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis on top,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    domain=-10:10,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-50,ymax=50,
    restrict y to domain=-50:50,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={},
    extra x ticks={-4.4721, 4.4721},
    extra x tick labels={$-2\sqrt{5}$, $2\sqrt{5}$},
    extra y ticks={44.721},
    extra y tick labels={$20\sqrt{5}$},    
    extra y tick style={y tick label style={right, xshift=0.25em}},
    yticklabel style={anchor=west},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0:7.746,blue] {15 * x - 0.25 * x^3};
\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=7.746:10,blue] {15 * x - 0.25 * x^3};
\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=-10:0,blue] {15 * x - 0.25 * x^3} node[right,pos=0.1,font=\footnotesize]{$y = 15x - \dfrac{1}{4} \, x^{3}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `yticklabel style={anchor=west}` was the culprit that was resulting in the labels on the wrong side. Commenting that out yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- I also changed the `fill` in `ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=none}` as it was whiting out some of the graph.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis on top,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    domain=-10:10,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-50,ymax=50,
    restrict y to domain=-50:50,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=none},% <-- changed from fill=none
    xtick={\empty},ytick={},
    extra x ticks={-4.4721, 4.4721},
    extra x tick labels={$-2\sqrt{5}$, $2\sqrt{5}$},
    extra y ticks={44.721},
    extra y tick labels={$20\sqrt{5}$},    
    extra y tick style={y tick label style={right, xshift=0.25em}},
    %yticklabel style={anchor=west},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0:7.746,blue] {15 * x - 0.25 * x^3};
\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=7.746:10,blue] {15 * x - 0.25 * x^3};
\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=-10:0,blue] {15 * x - 0.25 * x^3} node[right,pos=0.1,font=\footnotesize]{$y = 15x - \dfrac{1}{4} \, x^{3}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nicer graph than I expected!  I agree that the specification `fill=none` is appropriate here.  (Of course, I appreciate you taking the time to find the flaw in the code.)